# When should I edit my question versus delete and replace with a new post?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1009980/how-do-i-know-or-detect-font-style-versus-artificial-styling-typographic-abomin) that I now realize needs to be completely rewritten (new title, vastly rewritten text, add screenshots).

Should I edit or delete and replace it?

Are there general guidelines or principles for deciding?

Comment: I decided to just edit the question, so the question you are asking about, is  clearly indicated

Comment: Ramhound - What do you mean? What did you edit? It's not at all evident to me.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.superuser.com/posts/11009/revisions)

Comment: Ummm -- maybe you are working too hard. It appears that you replaced "question that" with "question that."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you referring to https://superuser.com/questions/1009980/fonts-visible-in-folder-but-not-in-office-2010-apps?

In general:

- If a question does not yet have answers, and the revised question would be asking about the same topic/problem/issue, then it should be improved to **clarify or make it more specific**.
- If a question already has answers, then you should **not** revise it **if the revised question would invalidate any of the answers**.

Comment: Oh! I just came back to this screen and noticed your stem question (missed it before). And, yes, "Fonts visible" is the question. I completely retitled and rewrote it.

Answer (score 2):

For the part about deleting:
There are advantages and ramifications to deleting a question and replacing it.

advantage: a new question will more likely be seen again. While a fully revised question will bring it up in active, only a "new" one will show in the newest.

Disadvantage: Deleting questions is a no-no and the machine that runs the place will begin to dislike you :-) After too many bad questions and deleted questions, even if they are deleted by you, it counts towards your bad question score, and eventually could get you question banned.  (This is hearsay I read from other questions about the machine warning/banning people, although I am sure someone else could verify it)

Adding a bounty to a question is a method to give it more visibility and put it in the featured set. Before blowing rep out on a bounty making it as readable and understandable (revised) as possible would be multi advantage. It then is likely to show on 2 lists, and it is revised to improve it.

Comment: Also: 1) If there is a long comments thread and you rewrite so that the comments are all irrelevant, ask a moderator to delete the comments so they aren't confusing and distracting.  2) In a case where there are no answers and the question has received downvotes, rewriting will still carry that baggage.  If you will be solving the downvote issues, delete and start over.

Comment: I can never encourage removal over editing content